# Issue with updating rows in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview where users can edit and update data in gridview but my issue is when i put some text in the Action field, nothing is updated. I have tried to run debug mode so i can watch what what is happening but i don't see the values i typed in the text box, it shows blank in my variable.  Here is my aspx code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  Width = "855px" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" Font-Names = "Arial" 
        OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" onrowediting="EditGridView1"
        onrowupdating="UpdateGridView1"  onrowcancelingedit="CancelEdit" CellPadding="3" 
                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" >
       <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQST_SK" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QUEST_SK")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate> 

            <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
        </asp:TemplateField> 

        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"  HeaderText = "Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAction" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ACTION")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAction" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("ACTION")%>' TextMode="MultiLine" Height="80px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>  
            <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>        
       </Columns> 
           <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
           <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
               HorizontalAlign="Left" />
           <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
           <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />         
    </asp:GridView>
```

here is my code behind:

```
protected void UpdateGridView1(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string QUEST_SK = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblQST_SK")).Text;
        string ACTION = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtAction")).Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update mytable set ACTION=@ACTION" +
         "where QUEST_SK=@QUEST_SK;" +
         "SELECT QUEST_SK, ACTION FROM mytable";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QUEST_SK", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = QUEST_SK;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACTION", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ACTION;
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using #Bind instead of #Eval for the TextBox controls?

Comment: no i haven't, but the weird thing is that everything worked fine for me before until i made some changes in the back-end table and the change was, i changed the QUEST_SK from bigint into identity column and that is all

Comment: Identity column is auto-increment so there's no need to insert a value into it. Do try uing #Bind, since it works 2-ways for controls where user can provide input i.e. read from data source as well as store user input.

Comment: This may be because of Binding Data on postback in page load. so try to avoid binding the data every time instead of just the first time.

Comment: i understand that and i am not inserting the identity column into a table but i am only using it in my where clause and you will see that if you look at my code

Comment: Vignesh, you were right and thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the function below  in Page Load Event :

```
Page_Load()
{

if(IsPostBack)
{
    return`;
}

}
```